# Cannot see the Facebook 'Like' button

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-like

i've checked the other similar questions and tried various solutions and none have worked.
Here's what i got:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_LA/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

---

<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/clavedrock" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false" data-font="verdana"></div>
```

I have checked with the debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug and theres no problem...

The website is: http://clavederock.com.ar

Can someone help me??
Thanks!

Comment: 1 error: `Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://www.clavederock.com.ar/ from frame with URL http://www.ustream.tv/embed/11856363?autoplay=true. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init().`

Comment: Thanks! i see... how can i fix this??

Comment: @irrelephant any suggestion on how to fix it?

Comment: Check ustream's documentation (well, if it exists) to understand why they are trying to "access" your page via javascript (that is the firs message you see on console). The second  message (`FB.getLoginStatus()...`) is the facebook's like button problem. My answer bellow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that you are loading facebook's like button by pointing to a non existent URL: "http://www.facebook.com/clavedrock" (I tried opening that address and it doesn't exists). I changed it (using chrome's console) to "http://www.clavederock.com.ar" and it worked! :)

You only have to change this:

```
data-href="http://www.facebook.com/clavedrock"
```

to this:

```
data-href="http://www.clavederock.com.ar"
```

(or create a facebook page for Clave de Rock.

Comment: It worked! BTW I already have a facebook page but i haven't plubished it yet (my bad..) Thanks again!!

Comment: You are welcome :) I saw the other message from ustream last time, but forgot to comment you about that :P